# Find dates after today [Express + mongoose]

Tags: node.js, express, web, mongoose

I building a web application that lists events in chronological order and I only want to list future events from a specific date, however my mongoose queries keep returning and empty object. If I query all events, my code works fine, but when ever I add filters, it always returns an empty object.

my model:

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
address: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},

start: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
end: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
url: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
img: {
    type: String,
    default: "noimage.jpg"
} });
```

my route

```
app.get('/events', (req, res) => {
Event.find({ date: { $gte: new Date(2018, 01, 01) } }).exec(function(err, events) {
    console.log(events)
    events.forEach(function(event) {
        const month = event.date.getMonth() + 1;
        const day = event.date.getDate();
        const year = event.date.getYear();
        event.formatDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    });
    res.render('events', {
        events: events,
    })
}) });
```

mongodb example object (this isnt the only one)

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5a736236ee687920e2fb736f"
},
"img": "hauntedhouse.jpg",
"name": "Holloween Party",
"date": "2017-10-31",
"description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium hic molestiae cum eaque? Officia, temporibus, nobis! In labore quod, esse alias, quos, ex quae eius enim quisquam autem fugit consectetur.",
"address": "Lorenzo \u201cLore\u201d Garcia Park - 413 E. Clark Ave",
"start": "6:00 PM",
"end": "10:00 PM",
"phone": "555-555-555",
"email": "asdf@asdf.com",
"url": "http://www.test.com",
"__v": 0 }
```

Comment: Do you know that in javascript Date `months` are zero-based? So `01` is February.

Comment: @ema Yes im aware of that, but thank you for letting me know. Right now, retrieving the proper data is my top priority

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my issue was how my dates were saved to mongodb. 
They needed to be in the following format:

"date": {
        "$date": "2017-10-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },